# C# UWP Difference between Toast notifications & Push notifications

Tags: c#, uwp

As far as i know, toast notifier in UWP is just like a messagebox. But the difference is messagebox will appear as a pop-up within the app. Where as Toast notification will appear out of the application.
And i don't know what is Push Notification.

Answer (score 0):

Push Notifications are send from the web server. For example, service can send push notification that there is a sale and you can buy app with a discount or that there is a new release and you can update your app or read 'what's new'. While Toasts are created with your local app code.

It's called Push since notification originate from webserver. You can poll server yourself, but it will be Pull approach. For more info regarding Push take a look at the following [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API).

For more info regarding Push Notifications in UWP see the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview).